# “Me” e “mim” são falados diferentemente?

Tags: fonologia, dialetos

No meu dileto:

1. *Me* tem principalmente duas pronúncias, **[me]** e **[mɪ]**. A pronúncia com /i/ é mais comum, mas ambas existem. Quando se tonizam, são **[ˈme]** e **[ˈmi]**.
2. *Mim* se pronuncia **[ˈmiŋ]**. Esta já é tônica. Falar com **[ɪ]** é bem inatural para mim.

Já vi muitas pessoas errando em diferenciar "me" de "mim" na escrita. Sempre achei que era porque "me" e "mim" eram normalmente falados como "mi'.

Por isso pergunto: diferenciar "me" de "mim", na fala, é o normal ou é algo dialetal?

Nas transcições fonéticas, usei o AFI (Alfabeto Fonético Internacional). *Vide* https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_Fon%C3%A9tico_Internacional;

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113155/discussion-on-question-by-schilive-me-e-mim-sao-falados-diferentemente).

Comment: Seria bom dar exemplos. Depende de onde aparece na frase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Portugal, sim. São **completamente** diferentes.

**"Me" soa [mɨ]** — talvez entre um "ê" e um "ü".
**"Mim" soa [mĩ]** — entre um "i" e um "ing".

Este site permite gerar IPA pt-PT: http://european-portuguese.info/pt/ipa#Foi%20ele%20que%20me%20deu,%20a%20mim.

> Foi ele que **me** deu, a **mim**.
>
> IPA:
> ˈfoj ˈe.ɫɨ kɨ **mɨ** ˈdew, ɐ **ˈmĩ**.

E este fala da pronúncia:
http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/cpp/acessibilidade/capitulo2_1.html

- O "e" de "me" soa como o "e" de "sabe": ['sabɨ]
- "Mim" soa como "sim" mas com /m/ em vez de /s/: ['sĩ]

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o [Portal da Língua](http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/), a pronúncia de *me* é /mɨ/ em Portugal, e /mi/ ou /mɪ/ no Brasil. A pronúncia de *mim* é /mˈĩ/ em Portugal, e /mˈĩ/ ou /mˈiɲ/ no Brasil.

Então, *me* e *mim* têm pronúncias diferentes, principalmente em que *me* é fraco, átono, e *mim* é forte, tônico. Daí, imagino, pronome átono e tônico.